# Redirecting Base URL in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

My Azure blob storage url looks like this:
https://mycompany.blob.core.windows.net/myplugin

I have files there which is meant to be used by a "source web app". This source web app expects that the above url direct to another file within the above directory:
https://mycompany.blob.core.windows.net/myplugin/myfile.json

Can someone suggest how to get this setup?

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone suggest how to get this setup?

As of today this functionality is not possible with Azure Blob Storage. For this functionality to work, Azure Blob Storage need to work like a web server which it is not. It is simply an object store where objects are exposed via a REST API.

You would need to use a proper web server.

Comment: Or you could use a Function App to redirect on the fly. `Your app -> call Function App -> return HTTP 301 with full URL to JSON in blob`. Docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook

Comment: evilSnobu, I have explored your suggestions and this is what I think we should be doing, can you please confirm? (Note that the source app is a 3rd party app, so we cannot make it call our Function). So, instead we will setup a blob storage webhook with an Azure Function with output bindings, where we return the JSON or whatever we need. In other words: 3rd Party App --> HTTP Call on Blob Storage base url --> Azure Function Output Bindings processes this and returns whatever 3rd Party app needs.

Answer (score 0):

It is still not possible to do it today using blob storage only however you can do it using an azure CDN endpoint in front of your azure blob storage and configure a redirection (via the cdn rules engine)

Some useful links:

- [CDN rules engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-rules-engine)
- [Rules engine features - url redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-rules-engine-reference-features#url-redirect)